# Error "cascade delete on"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

i have problem. I need add "cascade delete on" in CONSTRAINT [FK_SumaRoute_Suma] :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SumaRoute] (
    [Id]      INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [SumaId]  INT NOT NULL,
    [RouteId] INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_SumaRoute] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_SumaRoute_Suma] FOREIGN KEY ([SumaId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Suma] ([Id])  ***** HERE !!! *****,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_SumaRoute_Route] FOREIGN KEY ([RouteId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Route] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

But SQL Server return errors:

> Creating FK_Part_Suma1...
>   (104,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider:
>   Msg 1785, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Part_Suma1' on table 'Part' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   (104,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider:
>   Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
>   An error occurred while the batch was being executed.

My tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Suma] (
    [Id]       INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [SumaName] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Suma_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Route] (
    [Id]        INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [RouteName] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Route] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

**EDIT: Next tables**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Part] (
    [Id]       INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [PartName] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [SumaId]   INT           NOT NULL,
    [Place]    NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Time]     TIME (7)      NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Part] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Part_Suma1] FOREIGN KEY ([SumaId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Suma] ([Id])
);
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order] (
    [Id]             INT      IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [PartId]         INT      NOT NULL,
    [RouteId]        INT      NULL,
    [SumaId]         INT      NOT NULL,
    [DriverId]       INT      NULL,
    [Express]        BIT      CONSTRAINT [DF_Order_Express] DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [Status]         INT      CONSTRAINT [DF_Order_Status] DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [TimeLeft]       DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [StartTransport] DATETIME NULL,
    [Created]        DATETIME NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Order] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Order_Part] FOREIGN KEY ([PartId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Part] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Order_Route] FOREIGN KEY ([RouteId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Route] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Order_Suma] FOREIGN KEY ([SumaId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Suma] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Order_User] FOREIGN KEY ([DriverId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User] (
    [Id]            INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Pin]           NCHAR (4)      NOT NULL,
    [SumaIdSigned]  INT            NULL,
    [RouteIdSigned] INT            NULL,
    [Name]          NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Surname]       NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Type]          BIT            NOT NULL,
    [TokenGCM]      NVARCHAR (400) NULL,
    [TokenAccess]   NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [SignedTime]    DATETIME       NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_User_Route] FOREIGN KEY ([RouteIdSigned]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Route] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_User_Suma] FOREIGN KEY ([SumaIdSigned]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Suma] ([Id])
);
```

**I can remove Suma, Route and User. If i remove Suma row (id = 5) and any Order contain SumaId(5) so i need remove all Orders with sumaId(5).**

What i have doing pls?
Sorry my english :)

Comment: Apparently the problem is elsewhere. Error message is talking about `FK_Part_Suma1` which is not shown in your code. Can you share info about other tables?

Comment: Are the tables and references you are showing complete? Don't have `Suma`, `Route` and `Part` foreign keys to other tables? The schema in your question would not be a problem...

Comment: EDIT: this is completed db